# how make two dimensional array from two variable array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

this is my python code

```
dataheader = []
for listhead in head[11:]:
    dataheader.append(listhead)
    
databody = []
for listbody in body[11:]:
    databody.append(listbody)
    
combine = []
for i in range(len(databody)):
     combine.append(str(dataheader[i]))
     combine.append(str(databody[i]))
rawdata = np.reshape(combine, (-1, 2))    
print(rawdata)
```

from that code i get result like this

```
dataheader = ['2020/06/20', '2020/07/20', '2020/08/20']

databody = ['6', '7', '8']

rawdata = [['2020/06/20' '6'], ['2020/07/20' '7'], ['2020/08/20' '8']]
```

i want to change result of rawdata like this

```
rawdata = [['2020/06/20', '6'], ['2020/07/20', '7'], ['2020/08/20', '8']]
```

and like this

```
rawdata = [{'2020/06/20', '6'}, {'2020/07/20', '7'}, {'2020/08/20', '8'}]
```

please help me to fix this code. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need nested lists use `zip` with convert to nested lists in list comprehension:

```
dataheader = ['2020/06/20', '2020/07/20', '2020/08/20']

databody = ['6', '7', '8']

out1 = [list(x) for x in zip(dataheader, databody)]
```

Instead all your loops is possible use:

```
out1 = [list(x) for x in zip(head[11:], body[11:])]
```

If need sets:

```
out2 = [set(x) for x in zip(head[11:], body[11:])]
```

Or if need one element dictionaries in list:

```
out3 = [dict([x]) for x in zip(head[11:], body[11:])]
print (out3)
[{'2020/06/20': '6'}, {'2020/07/20': '7'}, {'2020/08/20': '8'}]
```

If need all element dictionary:

```
out4 = dict(zip(head[11:], body[11:]))
print (out4)
{'2020/06/20': '6', '2020/07/20': '7', '2020/08/20': '8'}
```

Comment: thank you, this code work for me. you save my time. but i get error on ```dict(x)``` _TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence_

Comment: @ZmxAtah - My bug, need add `[]` like `dict([x]) `

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a set for the items in your list:

```
dataheader = []
for listhead in head[11:]:
    dataheader.append(listhead)
    
databody = []
for listbody in body[11:]:
    databody.append(listbody)
    
combine = []
for i in range(len(databody)):
     temp_set = set()
     temp_set.add(str(dataheader[i]))
     temp_set.add(str(databody[i]))
     combine.append(temp_set)

print(combine)
```

Output:

```
[{'2020/06/20', '6'}, {'2020/07/20', '7'}, {'2020/08/20', '8'}]
```